# Buscar um array menor dentro de outro maior

Tags: python-3.x, lista

Eu tenho duas listas de frequências, uma observada e outra modelada. Acontece que quero encontrar todos os valores mais próximos das observadas dentro da modelada. A primeira tem comprimento de 38 e a segunda de 303. Fiz o seguinte

```
def find_nearest(array,value):
    return np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
indices = []
for k in range(0,len(observadas)):
    np.append(indices, find_nearest(modeladas,observadas[k])
print(indices)
```

Testei individualmente algumas das observadas dentro das modelas, e existem...
Mas o que fiz retorna [ ]
Sugestões?

Comment: Qual a linguagem?

Comment: Desculpe me, python3

Comment: Não falta a tag `numpy` ?